# Tableau server Map Cache zooming

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, tableau-api

I have a dashboard with custom geocoding uploaded to the tableau server, The dashboard works fine in the Desktop but take 12secs to execute each query/filter/zoom. When I see the networks i see there is a XHR request each time with takes the greatest time with high TTFB time. 
Can this be improved by any method ?
Can using nginx compression and load balancing increase the speed ?
Will additional layer of cloudflare caching will help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Tableau Server so far, but if the TTFB has a high value, that your server needs that much time to process your data.
Load balancing doesn't speed up a server, it just passes each request to a different server, but the TTFB for a single Request won't be faster.

I assume that only better server hardware can lower the TTFB. Or maybe a Tableau Cluster.